# Getting gridview data from dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So i have a field `type` where the user can type in either `ind` or `ud`, I need to make this field a dropdown so there is no other option than these two, so the user cant mess up.

I want the data field to be as the dropdown below. I hope I am making some sense.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSupStatus"> 
        <asp:ListItem>Ind</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Ud</asp:ListItem> 
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

my select and update string:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT [CHECKEDIN], [TIME], [ID] FROM [timereg] WHERE (([UNILOGIN] = @UNILOGIN) AND ([DATE] = @DATE))"
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE [timereg] Set [TIME]=@TIME, [CHECKEDIN]=@CHECKEDIN Where [id]=@id"
```

Comment: check http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-DropDownList-in-ItemTemplate-of-TemplateField-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx

Comment: Your approach is correct. What's the question?

Comment: the question really is, how do i get the [ID] into the dropdown, so if the user i registred in the DB it will displau the value set like "UD" and if edited then  something like "[CHECKEDIN] =@ddlSupStatus" know what i mean? updated the question with updatecommand

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking